# Store variable in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code that reads a row of characters from an array, assign the characters to an integer and then average all the integers of the row, it does this for every row in the array. As i am new to java i am  having trouble trying to store the average of each row (gpa) in another array. Here is what I have so far :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Grades.txt"));
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new File("Grades.txt"));

int size = 0;

while(in2.hasNextLine()) { 
  size++;
}

int count = 0;

double [] gpalist = new double[size] ; 

while(in.hasNextLine()) {
     size++;
     double gp = 0;
     double gpa = 0;
     String line = in.nextLine();
     double [] arraygpa = new double [7];

     if(line.length() == 0) {
        continue;
     }

     line = line.substring(line.length()-15, line.length());

     String[] letters = line.split(" ");

     for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

     if (letters[i].equals("H")) {
        gp += 7;
     }
     else if (letters[i].equals("D")) {
        gp += 6;
     }
     else if (letters[i].equals("C")) {
        gp += 5;
     }
     else if (letters[i].equals("P")) {
        gp += 4;
     }
     else if (letters[i].equals("F")) {
        gp += 0;
     }
     }

    gpalist[count++] = gp / letters.length;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gpalist));      

}
```

Here is the current output :

```
[5.75]
[6.75, 0.0]
[4.375, 0.0, 0.0]
[2.375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[4.125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[4.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[2.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I am trying to store the averages (gpa) in another array but my attempt is far from correct. The use of ArrayLists for the solution is prohibited unfortunately. I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear enough, i have edited my description. The problem is i am having trouble figuring out a way to store the average of each row (gpa) in another array

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList` if you are not sure how many lines in the text file:

```
ArrayList<Double> gpaList = new ArrayList<Double>();

while(in.hasNextLine()) {
     int gp = 0;
     double gpa = 0;
     String line = in.nextLine();

     if(line.length() == 0) {
        continue;
     }

     line = line.substring(line.length()-15, line.length());

     String[] letters = line.split(" ");

     for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

         if (letters[i].equals("H")) {
            gp += 7;
         }
         else if (letters[i].equals("D")) {
            gp += 6;
         }
         else if (letters[i].equals("C")) {
            gp += 5;
         }
         else if (letters[i].equals("P")) {
            gp += 4;
         }
         else if (letters[i].equals("F")) {
            gp += 0;
         }
     }
     gpaList.Add(gp / letters.length);
}
```

If you insist to use Array, then you can do, Assuming that you the number of line in your txt file is not more than `8`

```
int count = 0;
Double[] gpaList = new Double[8];
while(in.hasNextLine()) { 
    ....
    ....
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        ....
        ....
    } 
    gpaList[count++] = gp / letters.length;
}
```

But if you don't know how many Grades are there, the nearest solution would be count the line first.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Grades.txt"));
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new File("Grades.txt"));
int size = 0;
while(in2.hasNextLine()) { 
   size++;
}
int count = 0;
Double[] gpaList = new Double[size];   

while(in.hasNextLine()) { 
    ....
    ....
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        ....
        ....
    } 
    gpaList[count++] = gp / letters.length;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gpalist));
}
```

Comment: Actually the use of ArrayLists is prohibited for this solution

Comment: @AJJ To expand a little on the updated answer: Your problem was that you were trying to assign all the `gpa`s after your `while` loop (which clears and resets the `gpa` each time.  The second solution in this question moves the allocation to the `gpaList` into the `while` loop, so you store the data while it is still valid.  - I hope this helps. @TheQuickBrownFox, feel free to add this (or similar) to the question.

Comment: @Baldrickk thank you for the explanation.
For future purposes what would be the solution if the amount of grades was not known in advance?

Comment: @AJJ you'd have to do one or more of the following: 1) allocate an array larger than you think you would ever need before hand 2) stop and inform the user that it is incomplete (error) or 3) Use another data structure (one that can grow). Either `ArrayList`, or maybe another built-in data type that can grow like `List`.

Comment: @AJJ you can count the total line first, in another loop.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Would that loop be placed after the original while loop? EDIT: my mistake than the variables gp and letters would not be accessible.

Comment: I have attempted the third solution except i must have done something wrong as the output is incorrect, i have updated my original code to show what i have done.

Comment: @AJJ No. You will need two `while-loop` for that. check the update

Comment: ah before the original while loop. I tested that solution and in fact the print returned a blank screen.

Comment: @AJJ Check back your code. There might be something you missed

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox seems to be exactly the same, i have updated my original post as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably do not know the number of grades in advance, this is a good use case for the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List<Double> gpas = new ArrayList<Double>();
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
 int gp = 0;
 double gpa = 0;
 ...
 gpa = gp / letters.length;
 gpas.add(gpa);
 ...
} // End while
```

The ArrayList class has a couple of toArray methods, if you require a "simple" array later.

**Update:**

In the case where there are 8 grades per student, you can pre-initialize the array with that size, and keep an indexing variable outside the while-loop:

```
double[] gpas = new double[8];
int index = 0;
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
 int gp = 0;
 double gpa = 0;
 ...
 gpas[index] = gp / letters.length;
 index++;
 ...
} // End while
```

Comment: It is assumed that there are 8 grades per student, unfortunately i am unable to use ArrayLists

Comment: The second solution seems to work correctly, what if the grades were unknown beforehand?

Comment: Well, the ArrayList approach.

Comment: It's a rather "artificial" restriction to not be able to use List implementations. It's a very basic and useful datatype.

Comment: There would be no other solution without using an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, create an array that is big enough that you are sure it can hold all the grades (e.g. "We'll never have more than 2000 grades") and then keep track of how many entries in the array are actually used.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with storing all the line values? If so you just create list variable and store values inside. Like this:

```
List<Double> avrageGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and then when you have line avrage you just do this:

```
avrageGrades.Add(gpa);
```

If this is the function you can then just return avrageGrades when while ends.

But if you want an array, then you have to know nummber of lines. You first have to cound nummber of lines. Create an array with the size of number of the lines. And then have a counter inside of while so that you will know which line you have and then just do:

> avrageGrades[line] = gpa;